# Google visualisation target line

Tags: javascript, line, visualization, target

I'm trying to add a target line in Google visualisation graph. Only when there is only one result, the target line is a dot instead of an expected line.

```
chart.draw(data, 
{
    hAxis: {title: '', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
    seriesType: 'bars', 
    series: {1: {type: 'line'}}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

[Combo Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#combo_chart)

Use data point for the line chart as one of the columns in the DataTable and specify in options this column to be the "series"-"type"-"line" and other columns are visualized in a ColumnChart.

OR

[Stepped Area Chart](http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart)